# Angular 2, ASP.Net Core и базовый CRUD через angular-сервис

Tags: c#, angular2, typescript, asp.net-core

Приветствую. Пробую себя в Angular 2 Asp.net Core. Возник стопор при работе с сервисом для получения данных с сервера. Не могу понять почему шаблон из "[учебника](https://metanit.com/sharp/aspnetcore/1.2.php)" не работает. Выдает следующее:[image]

```
Аргумент типа "(data: Order[]) => Order[]" нельзя назначить параметру типа "((value: Order) => void) | undefined".
  Тип "(data: Order[]) => Order[]" не может быть назначен для типа "(value: Order) => void".
    Типы параметров "data" и "value" несовместимы.
      Тип "Order" не может быть назначен для типа "Order[]".
        Свойство "length" отсутствует в типе "Order".
```

Если кто сталкивался ,помогите пожалуйста разобраться.

Сорцы:
tendercreate.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms/src/model';

import { OrdersService } from "../../services/orders.service"
import { Order } from "../../shared/models";

@Component({
    selector: 'tender-create',
    templateUrl: './tendercreate.component.html',
    styleUrls:  ["./tendercreate.component.css"],
    providers: [OrdersService]
})
export class TenderCreateComponent implements OnInit{  
    order: Order= new Order();
    orders: Order[];

    constructor(private ordersService: OrdersService){}

    ngOnInit(){
        this.loadOrders();
    }

    loadOrders(){
        this.ordersService.getOrders()
        .subscribe((data: Order[]) => this.orders = data);
    }

    onSubmit(){
        // this.ordersService.createOrders(this.order)
        // .subscribe((data: any)=> this.orders.push(data));    
    }    
}
```

orders.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Order } from '../shared/models';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class OrdersService {
    private url = "/api/orders";

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    }

    getOrders(): Observable<Order>{
        return this.http.get(this.url);
    }

    createOrders(neworder: Order){
        return this.http.post(this.url,neworder);
    }

}
```

models.ts

```
export class Order {
    constructor(
        public Caption?: string,
        public Text?: string,
        public Geomap?:string,
        public Cost?: number,
        public Viewers?: number,
        public UsersId?: number,
        public ThereImages?: boolean,
        public ThereFiles?: boolean
    ){}
}
export class User{
    constructor(){}
}
```

Пробовал по этому [ответу](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37221062/observable-not-assignable-to-type-observablesometype),но не вышло.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот тут `Observable<Order>` компилятору указывается, что тип *внутри* `Observable` - `Order`

А вот тут `.subscribe((data: Order[])` - уже `Order[]`.

---

Чтобы все заработало, эти типы должны совпадать.

Судя по названию везде должно быть `Order[]`.

Кроме того, так как теперь разбором json занимается сам `HttpClient`, при вызове ему можно указать какой тип ожидается:

```
return this.http.get<Order[]>(this.url);
```

В противном случае будет считаться, что возвращается `Object`.

Comment: Да,извиняюсь, при изменении `Observable<Order>` на `Observable<Order[]> ` , ранее пробовал.
выйдаст:


`Тип "Observable<Object>" не может быть назначен для типа "Observable<Order[]>".
  Тип "Object" не может быть назначен для типа "Order[]".
    Тип Object можно назначить малому количеству других типов. Возможно, вы хотели использовать тип any?
      Свойство "length" отсутствует в типе "Object".`


Так же если убрать возвращаемое `Observable<Order>` в целом ничего не изменится. Потому извиняюсь что не убрал это заранее, т.к. судя по всему оно не влияет на итог.

Comment: @LennyMarks, не понял твой комментарий. Когда ты попробовал `Observable<Order[]>` то показало другую ошибку?

Comment: Да, указывающую что тип несовместим с Object и что отсутствует свойство length в Object.

Comment: @LennyMarks, минуту обновлю ответ

Comment: Благодарю! Проблема решена!
Правда теперь страница при загрузке дропается(без ошибок,на конструкторе).Но это уже другая проблема. Не связаная с данным вопросом.